# Find specific query in Query Store

Tags: sql-server-2016, query-store

I have enabled Query Store on a database. I have a specific query which I want to track. I have a lot of details about the query from sp_BlitzCache (like SQL Text, SQL Handle, SQL Hash, Plan Cache Handle/Hash, etc...).

Am I able to search Query Store with the info from sp_BlitzCache to track down the query there? I want to force a specific execution plan because the query suffers parameter sniffing issues.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way to do this is to query the Query Store views directly for the info you've gained from the plan cache:

```
SELECT 
    qsq.query_id,
    qsq.last_execution_time,
    qsqt.query_sql_text
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
    INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
        ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
WHERE
    qsqt.query_sql_text LIKE '%your query text%';
```

The `sys.query_store_query` table also has some of the other fields (`query_hash`, `last_compile_batch_sql_handle`, `statement_sql_handle`, etc), which might find the query you're looking for more reliably.

Basically the point of that is to find the "query id" in Query Store, as you'll need that to find plans for it and force one.

Once you have the `query_id` in hand, you can go to the UI in SSMS and find the query using the "Tracked Queries" node:

[image: screenshot of tracked queries tab and text box]

From there you can click on the plan you want, and click "Force Plan" to force it:

[image: Screenshot of force plan button]

Answer (score 10):

The UI is super unfriendly, but you can also search query text directly from the "<kbd>Tracked Queries</kbd>" dashboard. Given my garbage database with only 2 system queries in it...

```sql
select 
    query_text_id, 
    left(query_sql_text,50) as query_sql_text 
from sys.query_store_query_text
```

...showing...

```
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| query_text_id | query_sql_text                                     |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 1             | (@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4 |
| 2             | SELECT db.name as HasMemoryOptimizedObjects from m |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

..I can click on the "Magnifying Glass " icon in the "Tracking Query" search box...

[image: Magnifying Glass icon on Tracking Query input bar]

This will pop out the following input form...

[image: Query Text search input form. A red box encloses the search field. A blue box encloses the magnifying glass icon.]

If you input the query test you want to search into the search bar (boxed in red in the screencap) and the press enter or click the magnifying glass icon (boxed in blue), you can browse Query ID, Query Text ID, and Query Text from a builtin UI (unfriendly though it may be to access).

By way of example, you can see in the following screen cap I have searched the letter "a" and get back both queries...

[image: Searching the letter "a" in the input form]

...while in the next screen cap I have searched the more selective string "HasMemoryOptimizedObjects", which returns only the matching query text

[image: Searching the string "HasMemoryOptimizedObjects" in the input form]

Comment: I didn't know about this 

Comment: @JoshDarnell they do a good job of hiding it 

Comment: How to honor an equally correct answer with just another approach? :)

Comment: Shame you can't search by query hash (which is what Azure SQL Analytics keeps giving me).

Comment: @Simon_Weaver if you check the docs for the [query_store_query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-query-transact-sql#:~:text=query_hash) system view referenced in the accepted answer, you'll find `query_hash` is a column exposed in this set 

Comment: @PeterVandivier I wasn't clear but I meant to say I wish it was directly searchable in this dialog box which unfortunately it isn't. Thanks for your reply though :-) It's simple enough to find it but an extra step is always a pain when you have to search 50 of them!